# Фрактальное сжатие изображений

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, фракталы

Я пишу алгоритм фрактального сжатия изображений. Нашёл несколько материалов по данному алгоритму, как русскоязычных, так и зарубежных. Основой для меня стала книга Ватолина - Методы сжатия данных.

После реализации компрессии у меня возникли проблемы с декомпрессией. И вместо стабильного изображения я получаю нечто мало похожее на оригинал. Возможно у меня проблемы с нахождением сдвига по яркости для каждого рангового блока. Я пробовал чередовать знаки всех сдвигов по яркости при каждой итерации декомпрессии, тогда рисунок получался более похож на оригинал, но всё же не достигалась сходимость к стабильному изображению.

Возможно, вы сможете помочь мне найти ошибку или же понять, где в самом алгоритме у меня недочеты.
Класс с непосредственными алгоритмами компрессии и декомпрессии.

```
class Coder:

def Compression(self, string, N):
    # Открываем изображение.
    image = Image.open(string)
    #image.show()
    width = image.size[0]  # Определяем ширину.
    height = image.size[1]  # Определяем высоту.
    # newimage = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), (0, 0, 0))
    # draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newimage)  # Создаем инструмент для рисования.
    # pixel = image.load()  # Выгружаем значения пикселей.
    # print(width)
    # print(height)
    outFile = open("Compressed file.txt", "w")
    range_size = N
    outFile.write(str(width) + ' ' + str(height) + '\n')
    outFile.write(str(range_size) + '\n')
    range_num_width = width // range_size
    range_num_height = height // range_size


    domain_size = range_size * 2
    domain_num_width = width // domain_size
    domain_num_height = height // domain_size

    RangeBlockList = []
    for i in range(range_num_width):
        for j in range(range_num_height):
            # Создаем ранговые блоки
            RangeBlock = BlockClass.Block(image, range_size, i, j, 0)
            # RangeBlock.Show()
            RangeBlockList.append(RangeBlock)
    RangeBlockList.reverse() #Разворачиваем список

    DomainBlockList = []
    for i in range(domain_num_width):
        for j in range(domain_num_height):
            for k in range(8):
                # Создаем доменные блоки со всеми вариантами симетрии
                DomainBlock = BlockClass.Block(image, domain_size, i, j, k)
                #DomainBlock.Show()
                DomainBlockList.append(DomainBlock)
    DomainBlockList.reverse()

    tt = 0
    # Компрессия
    RangeBlockListCopy = RangeBlockList.copy()
    while(RangeBlockListCopy):
        RangeBlock = RangeBlockListCopy.pop()
        DomainBlockListCopy = DomainBlockList.copy()
        min_distance = sys.maxsize
        while(DomainBlockListCopy):
            DomainBlock = DomainBlockListCopy.pop()
            # Запоминаем координаты текущего преобразования
            current_coor_x = DomainBlock.coor_x
            current_coor_y = DomainBlock.coor_y
            current_coeff = DomainBlock.coeff
            current_shift = L2.L2().Shift(RangeBlock, DomainBlock)
            current_distance = L2.L2().Distance(RangeBlock, DomainBlock, current_shift)
            #current_shift = L2.L2().OOO(RangeBlock, DomainBlock)
            #current_distance = L2.L2().RRR(RangeBlock, DomainBlock, current_shift)
            if (current_distance < min_distance):
                min_distance = current_distance
                best_coor_x = current_coor_x
                best_coor_y = current_coor_y
                best_coeff = current_coeff
                best_shift = current_shift
                print(best_coor_x)
                print(best_coor_y)
                print(best_coeff)
                print(best_shift)
        print("!!!!!")
        print(tt)
        tt = tt + 1
        outFile.write(str(best_coor_x) + ' ' + str(best_coor_y) + ' ' + str(best_coeff) + ' ' + str(best_shift) + '\n')

    outFile.close()

def Decompression(self):
    decFile = open("Compressed file.txt", "r")
    # Считываем все коэффиценты из файла
    String = decFile.read().replace("\n", " ").split(" ")

    count = 0
    width = (int)(String[count])
    count = count + 1
    height = (int)(String[count])
    count = count + 1

    range_size = (int)(String[count])
    count = count + 1

    # Создаём изображение
    #newimage = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
    newimage = Image.open("Expanded file.png")
    range_num_width = width // range_size
    range_num_height = height // range_size


    domain_size = range_size * 2
    #domain_num_width = width // domain_size
    #domain_num_height = height // domain_size

    # Разбиваем созданное изображение на ранговые блоки
    RangeBlockList = []
    for i in range(range_num_width):
        for j in range(range_num_height):
            # Создаем ранговые блоки
            RangeBlock = BlockClass.Block(newimage, range_size, i, j, 0)
            #RangeBlock.Show()
            RangeBlockList.append(RangeBlock)
    RangeBlockList.reverse()  # Разворачиваем список

    # Создаем доменные блоки по коэффицентам из сжатого файла
    DomainBlockList = []
    for i in range(range_num_width):
        for j in range(range_num_height):
            current_x = (int)(String[count])
            count = count + 1
            current_y = (int)(String[count])
            count = count + 1
            current_rotate = (int)(String[count])
            count = count + 1
            current_shift = (float)(String[count])
            count = count + 1
            #print(str(current_x) + ' ' + str(current_y) + ' ' + str(current_rotate) + ' ' + str(current_shift))
            DomainBlock = BlockClass.Block(newimage, domain_size, current_y, current_x, current_rotate)
            DomainBlock.SetShift((-current_shift))
            #DomainBlock.Show()
            DomainBlockList.append(DomainBlock)
    DomainBlockList.reverse()

    # Декомпрессия
    RangeBlockListCopy = RangeBlockList.copy()
    DomainBlockListCopy = DomainBlockList.copy()
    FinalRangeBlockList = []
    while(RangeBlockListCopy):
        RangeBlock = RangeBlockListCopy.pop()
        DomainBlock = DomainBlockListCopy.pop()
        #DomainBlock.Show()
        # RangePixels = RangeBlock.Blockimage.load()  # Выгружаем значения пикселей.
        DomainPixels = DomainBlock.Blockimage.load()
        Bufferimage = Image.new("RGB", (range_size, range_size), (255, 255, 255))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(Bufferimage)  # Создаем инструмент для рисования.
        for i in range(range_size):
            for j in range(range_size):
                R = (int)(0.75 * ((DomainPixels[i * 2, j * 2][0]) + (DomainBlock.DecompressionShift)))
                G = (int)(0.75 * ((DomainPixels[i * 2, j * 2][1]) + (DomainBlock.DecompressionShift)))
                B = (int)(0.75 * ((DomainPixels[i * 2, j * 2][2]) + (DomainBlock.DecompressionShift)))
                draw.point((i, j), (R, G, B))
                #Создаём новые изображения для каждого рангового блока
        FinalRangeBlock = BlockClass.Block(Bufferimage, range_size, 0, 0, 0)
        #FinalRangeBlock.Show()
        FinalRangeBlock.SetCoordinate(RangeBlock.coor_x, RangeBlock.coor_y)
        FinalRangeBlockList.append(FinalRangeBlock)
    FinalRangeBlockList.reverse()

    Newdraw = ImageDraw.Draw(newimage)  # Создаем инструмент для рисования.
    FinalRangeBlockListCopy = FinalRangeBlockList.copy()
    while(FinalRangeBlockListCopy):
        FinalRangeBlock = FinalRangeBlockListCopy.pop()
        #FinalRangeBlock.Show()
        FinalRangePixels = FinalRangeBlock.Blockimage.load()
        for i in range(range_size):
            for j in range(range_size):
                R = FinalRangePixels[i, j][0]
                G = FinalRangePixels[i, j][1]
                B = FinalRangePixels[i, j][2]
                Newdraw.point(((i + FinalRangeBlock.coor_x * range_size), (j + FinalRangeBlock.coor_y * range_size)),(R, G, B))

    newimage.save("Expanded file.png")
    newimage.close()
    decFile.close()
```

Вся программа целиком расположена по ссылке ниже.

https://github.com/TakingAway/Fractal-Compression

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Тоже хороший вопрос, зря удалили. Тут не хватает примера входных данных и подробностей про желаемый результат. Они нужны, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ваши результаты. Без этого бывает сложно даже понять, в чем заключается проблема, не говоря уже о том, чтобы найти ее в коде.